# Assessment of Template Parameter

Tags: c++

Is there a ready function which can take a template parameter as an argument and determine that it is a user defined types(class or struct) or built-in data types(int, float, char...) ?

Comment: Check out [`<type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [std::is_arithmetic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) template, which determines if the template parameter is an integer or a floating point type.

By process of elimination, the only remaining options are: pointer or a reference, a class, and `void`. Maybe an enum of some kind, too. It's unclear from your question how you want to classify those, but, if necessary, adding some additional checks on top of `std::is_arithmetic` should make it possible to disambiguate the given type further.

Comment: Note `std::is_fundamental` covers `void` and `std::nullptr_t` in addition to arithmetic types. On top of that, there are arrays, pointers & member pointers, and references. It might be easier starting from `is_class` and `is_union` and checking whether those fail, plus removing cv-qualifiers and pointers and/or references, depending on what exactly the OP wants.